# Elasticsearch: match exact keywords with special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing tags as an array of `keywords`:

```
...
Tags: {
   type: "keyword"
},
...
```

Resulting in arrays like this:

```
Tags: [
    "windows",
    "opengl",
    "unicode",
    "c++",
    "c",
    "cross-platform",
    "makefile",
    "emacs"
]
```

I thought that as I am using the `keyword` type I could easily do exact search terms, as it is not supposed to be using any analyser.

Apparently I was wrong! this gives me results:

```
body.query.bool.must.push({term: {"_all": "c"}}); # 38 results
```

But this doesn't:

```
body.query.bool.must.push({term: {"_all": "c++"}}); # 0 results
```

Although there are obviously instances of this tag, as seen above.

If I use `body.query.bool.must.push({match: {"_all": search}});` instead (using `match` instead of `term`) then "c" and "c++" returns the exact same results, which is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using [_all - Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html), which uses an analyzer (standard by default). Make a small test with your data to be sure:

**Test 1:**

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/script/test/_search \
  -d '{
  "query": {
        "term" : { "_all": "c++"}
  }
}'
```

**Test 2:**

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/script/test/_search \
  -d '{
  "query": {
        "term" : { "tags": "c++"}
  }
}'
```

In my test second query returns documents, first not.

Do you really need to search with multiple fields? If so, you can override the default analyzer of _all field - for a quick test I put an index with settings like this:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test" : {
            "_all" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "analyzer" : "keyword"},
            "properties": {
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can create [Custom _all Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html).

Solutions like [Multi Field query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field), that allow to define list of fields to be searched over would rather behave like your example with `body.query.bool.must.push({match: {"_all": search}});`.